# Annotate HTML files without editing raw HTML

Tags: notes, html

I would like to add annotations (highlights and notes) to HTML files saved on my Android phone, without having to edit the raw HTML. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the HTML file to a PDF file, using a conversion app like [Convert web to PDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smobileteam.pdf.activity&hl=en). Then annotate the PDF file using a PDF app that supports adding and editing annotations, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader.